# Fetch data form two dates with different year in php i.e.11/01/2016 to 01/03/2017

Tags: php, date, between

I am trying to fetch data from two dates and its not working.
My table in database is simple in this format 11/30/2016.
Now i want to fetch data form 11/30/2016 to 01/03/2017 but its not showing.

here my code

```
$date_from='11/30/2016'; 
$date_to='01/03/2017';
$querymain="select * from table_name where created BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'";
```

Comment: Is the data type of your column date/datetime or varchar? Also saying `ASAP` doesn't get a faster response.

Comment: paste screen shot of your table structure here

Comment: Try with this: `select * from table_name where DATE(created) BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'`

Comment: Why don't you use date_format() function of MySQL DB... I think DB is not following your date format because by default date format is "YYYY-mm-dd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your date format like this

```
$date_from='2016-11-30'; 
$date_to='2017-01-03';
//using php  you can convert your date like
$date_from = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("11/30/2016"));
$date_to=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("01/03/2017"));
$querymain="select * from table_name where DATE(`created`) BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'";

 try this i hope this is working for you.
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.
But in my database my "created" row in this this format.
11/01/2016
"m-d-Y"

Answer (score 1):

If your `created` column is date then you have to check date format in 2016-01-02 i.e. `YYYY-mm-dd` format for mysql.

Just try this.

```
$querymain="select * from table_name where created BETWEEN '".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date_from))."' AND '".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date_to))."'";
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.
But in my database my "created" row in this this format.
11/01/2016
"m-d-Y"

Comment: what is data type for created column? varchar or date?

Comment: i am using "varchar"

Comment: you should change to date data type and then you can check between.